# replace() function is not replacing 'e' character

Tags: python

My code should recognize the vowel letters and remove them from input string using the `replace()` function. However it works fine except for the `'e'` letter.

If the input is `"Hey look Words!"` the output is `"Hey lk Wrds!"`.
It identifies the 'e' only if if the "vowels" string is equal to `"e"` or `"eE"` only!

I am curious to know why?

```
def anti_vowel(text):
vowles="AaEeOoIiUu"
newstr=""
for i in text:
    if i in vowles:
        newstr=text.replace(i,"")

return newstr
```

Comment: Irony of "too many e's in title" :)

Answer (score 6):

You are placing only the *last replacement result* in `newstr`. All your previous `str.replace()` results are discarded.

For your input text `Hey look Words!`, the last vowel encountered is `o` so only `o` is replaced. The `e` replacement did take place and was stored in `newstr` but that value was then discarded when you set `newstr` to the result of the `o` replacement. It thus depends on the *input string* what vowel exactly will remain replaced; for the sentence `'The cat sat on the mat'` it'll be `a` as that is the last vowel you test and replace.

Just loop directly over `vowels` and replace each of those characters; it is save to call `str.replace()` where the first argument is not present. Store the result *back in `text`* so that any subsequent replacements stick:

```
def anti_vowel(text):
    vowels = "AaEeOoIiUu"
    for vowel in vowels:
        text = text.replace(vowel, "")
    return text
```

Better still, use the [`str.translate()` method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate) to replace *all* vowels in one go:

```
# Python 2 version
def anti_vowel(text):
    vowels = "AaEeOoIiUu"
    return text.translate(None, vowels)

# Python 3 version
def anti_vowel(text):
    vowels = str.maketrans(dict.fromkeys("AaEeOoIiUu"))
    return text.translate(vowels)
```

`str.translate()` makes all replacements at once; the method changed between Python 2 `str` and Python 3 `str`, but in both versions all the vowels are ignored as the new string is built, without any further loops.

Comment: I was trying to answer but I found your answer and I couldn't resist from up voting ur explanation  :)

Comment: Know I understand what I did, thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 1):

You should change your code to:

```
def anti_vowel(text):
    vowles="AaEeOoIiUu"
    newstr=text
    for i in newstr:
        if i in vowles:
            newstr=newstr.replace(i,"")

    return newstr
```

Then you will acummulate each replacement in your final string.

The way you are doing you always use the original string and replace only one group of chars ('Ee', 'Aa', etc...) in each iteration. So, in the end, you get a result of only one of these groups replaced in the original string.

Answer (score 1):

There's no reason to iterate through all the letters in the word; the `replace()` method does that for you. And you are erasing `newstr` every time, so by the end, all you're doing is replacing `u`. Here's what you need to do.

```
def anti_vowel(text):
    vowels = "AaEeIiOoUu"
    for i in vowels:
        text = text.replace(i, "")
    return text
```

This way, each time you replace text, you save and keep the replaced string. What you were doing earlier was making `newstr` into `text` without `A`, then replacing `newstr` with `text` sans `a` (but with `A`), so on and so forth. The end result was `text` without `u` but with everything else.